# Get identity of row inserted in Snowflake Datawarehouse

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I have a table with an auto-incrementing ID column, I'd like to be able to insert a row into that table, and get the ID of the row I just created. I know that generally, StackOverflow questions need some sort of code that was attempted or research effort, but I'm not sure where to begin with Snowflake. I've dug through their [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/index.html) and I've found nothing for this.

The best I could do so far is try `result_scan()` and `last_query_id()`, but these don't give me any relevant information about the row that was inserted, just confirmation that a row was inserted.

I believe what I'm asking for is along the lines of MS SQL Server's `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function.

**Is there a Snowflake equivalent function for MS SQL Server's `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`?**

EDIT: for the sake of having code in here:

```
CREATE TABLE my_db..my_table
(
    ROWID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    some_number INT,
    a_time TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9),
    b_time TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9),
    more_data VARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT INTO my_db..my_table
(
    some_number,
    a_time,
    more_data
)
VALUES
(1, my_time_value, some_data);
```

I want to get to that auto-increment `ROWID` for this row I just inserted.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance...don't you just want the MAX(ROWID)? So... SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM my_db.my_table;

Comment: @JonJaussi Pretend that 5-20 other processes are inserting records into this table at the same time. `MAX(ROWID)` might grab a row that was created by another process in that same time period.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. Is there a "natural key" in your data? Some concatenated combination of other fields in the record that you are inserting that would define the record as unique? The idea is you could lookup the ROWID using the "natural key" (Example: some_number | a_time | more_data)?

Comment: @JonJaussi I'm doing something to that effect now, but I feel it's a sloppy way to go about this. I was really hoping for a more proper way to get that `ROWID`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**NOTE: The answer below can be not 100% correct in some very rare cases, see the UPDATE section below**

## Original answer

Snowflake does not provide the equivalent of `SCOPE_IDENTITY` today.

However, you can exploit Snowflake's [time travel](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/at-before.html) to retrieve the maximum value of a column right after a given statement is executed.

Here's an example:

```
create or replace table x(rid int identity, num int);
insert into x(num) values(7);
insert into x(num) values(9);
-- you can insert rows in a separate transaction now to test it
select max(rid) from x AT(statement=>last_query_id());
----------+
 MAX(RID) |
----------+
 2        |
----------+
```

You can also save the `last_query_id()` into a variable if you want to access it later, e.g.

```
insert into x(num) values(5);
set qid = last_query_id();
...
select max(rid) from x AT(statement=>$qid);
```

Note - it will be usually correct, but if the user e.g. inserts a large value into `rid` manually, it might influence the result of this query.

## UPDATE

**Note, I realized the code above might rarely generate incorrect answer.**

Since the execution order of various phases of a query in a distributed system like `Snowflake` can be non-deterministic, and Snowflake allows concurrent INSERT statements, the following might happen

- Two queries, `Q1` and `Q2`, do a simple single row `INSERT`, start at roughly the same time
- `Q1` starts, is a bit ahead
- `Q2` starts
- `Q1` creates a row with value `1` from the `IDENTITY` column
- `Q2` creates a row with value `2` from the `IDENTITY` column
- `Q2` gets ahead of `Q1` - **this is the key part**
- `Q2` commits, is marked as finished at time `T2`
- `Q1` commits, is marked as finished at time `T1`

Note that `T1` is later than `T2`. Now, when we try to do `SELECT ... AT(statement=>Q1)`, we will see the state as-of `T1`, including all changes from statements before, hence including the value `2` from `Q2`. Which is not what we want.

The way around it could be to add a `unique identifier` to each `INSERT` (e.g. from a separate SEQUENCE object), and then use a `MAX`.

Sorry. Distributed transactions are hard :)

Comment: This looks promising. I'll give this a try shortly and report back!

Comment: Sorry, I realized my answer might generate wrong results, updated it.

Comment: @MarcinZukowski is Snowflake working on fixing this?  I am tasked with investigating Snowflake for our company and currently the one and only showstopper I see is this issue. From Snowflake Community Forums, it appears no progress is made. Any color would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JohnZabroski It's on our todo list, but no active development as of now. If this is blocking you, please raise it through your sales/support channel, this might help prioritizing it.

Comment: Just reporting back after having used this for over a year - @MarcinZukowski is correct with his update, we experience concurrency issues with this method. With that said, I haven't had time to update the feature that implements this with a `unique identifier` in each `INSERT`. To be fair to snowflake, in my use case, it's supporting some back end features to a website, which isn't really what data warehouses exist for in the first place.

Comment: @MarcinZukowski What about using CHANGE TRACKING? I was playing around with this:
```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MYTEST (
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
VAL1 VARCHAR);

ALTER TABLE MYTEST SET CHANGE_TRACKING = TRUE;

set ts1 = current_timestamp();
INSERT INTO MYTEST(VAL1) VALUES('Salut!');
set ts2 = current_timestamp();
select *
 from mytest
   changes(information => append_only)
  at(timestamp => $ts1)
  end(timestamp => $ts2);
```
Do you think this could be a valid approach?

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a table with an auto-incrementing ID column, I'd like to be
> able to insert a row into that table, and get the ID of the row I just
> created.

FWIW, here's a slight variation of the current accepted answer (using Snowflake's 'Time Travel' feature) that gives any column values "of the row I just created." It applies to auto-incrementing sequences and more generally to any column configured with a `default` (e.g. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` or `UUID_STRING()`). Further, I believe it avoids any inconsistencies associated with a second query utilizing `MAX()`.

Assuming this table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE my_db.my_table
(
    ROWID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    some_number INT,
    a_time TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9),
    b_time TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9),
    more_data VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Make sure the 'Time Travel' feature (`change_tracking`) is enabled for this table with:

```
ALTER TABLE my_db.my_table SET change_tracking = true;
```

Perform the `INSERT` per usual:

```
INSERT INTO my_db.my_table
(
    some_number,
    a_time,
    more_data
)
VALUES
(1, my_time_value, some_data);
```

Use the `CHANGES` clause with `BEFORE(statement...` and `END(statement...` specified as `LAST_QUERY_ID()` to `SELECT` the row(s) added to `my_table` which are the precise result of the previous `INSERT` statement (with column values that existed the moment the row(s) was(were) added, including any defaults):

```
SET insertQueryId=LAST_QUERY_ID();
SELECT
    ROWID,
    some_number,
    a_time,
    b_time,
    more_data
FROM my_db.my_table
    CHANGES(information => default)
    BEFORE(statement => $insertQueryId)
    END(statement => $insertQueryId);
```

For more information on the `CHANGES`, `BEFORE`, `END` clauses see the Snowflake documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/changes.html#changes).

Answer (score 0):

New answer to an old question here, as @MarcinZukowski good answer relies on [Time Travel](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-time-travel) it may be difficult to get right in a distributed environment.

Instead of using `AUTOINCREMENT` directly in the definition of the table column, we can use a [`SEQUENCE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences) separate from the table definition, and use it for the `DEFAULT` value of the identity column.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE my_table_seq;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    ROWID INT DEFAULT my_table_seq.nextval,
    some_number INT,
    a_time TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9),
    b_time TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9),
    more_data VARCHAR(10)
);
```

When inserting a new item, we can now use the next id in the sequence to insert it explicitly:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SET row_id = (SELECT my_table_seq.nextval id);
INSERT INTO my_table
(
    rowid,
    some_number,
    a_time,
    more_data
)
VALUES
($row_id, 1, current_timestamp(), 'some_data');
SELECT $row_id;
COMMIT;
```

Inside that transaction you can grab that `$row_id` value and do something else, like inserting related data into another table. Above we simply do a `SELECT $row_id;` to output it.

It also works as a single line statement where you *don't* need to capture the identity of the new item:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_db..my_table
(
    some_number,
    a_time,
    more_data
)
VALUES
(1, current_timestamp(), 'some_data');
```