# Snowflake JDBC driver does not support GetGeneratedKeys

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the auto-incremented key of the table in which I am inserting. However, Snowflake simply throws this exception 
`org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToCreateStatementException: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`

Does anyone know if the latest versions of Snowflake DB support this or not?

Comment: You should ask the developers of the Snowflake JDBC driver if they support it.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837950/get-identity-of-row-inserted-in-snowflake-datawarehouse

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should ask the developers of the Snowflake JDBC driver if they support it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would recommend using this as a reference for COPY INTO a table from an S3 bucket reference: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/how-to-copy-into-a-table-with-an-auto-increment-column

It looks like that it is optimal to have a staged version first with the table defined the column with auto-increment.

Can you please share how you are inserting and creating the table data that throws you this error?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake [JDBC driver documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-api.html) doesn't mention `getGeneratedKeys()` method.

At least Snowflake JDBC Driver 3.12.10 doesn't support support [Statement#getGeneratedKeys()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys())

`SnowflakeStatementV1.java` has this implementation which returns an empty ResultSet which is a bad implementation. According to JDBC API it should throw `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` since the feature clearly is not supported.

```java
  @Override
  public ResultSet getGeneratedKeys() throws SQLException {
    logger.debug("getGeneratedKeys()");
    raiseSQLExceptionIfStatementIsClosed();
    return new SnowflakeResultSetV1.EmptyResultSet();
  }
```