# using result scan of last statement in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Will there be any possible side effects with use of of the auto generated column from  resultscan of last query_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't understand how you will use the resultscan and last_query_id to fetch the generated column.

There is a method suggested by Marcin, which uses last_query_id and time travel:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53903693/12550965

But it may generate an incorrect answer in ***rare*** situations.

If you need to get IDs (or any auto-increment column), I think you can use a sequence. You can read it before the INSERT, and then call the INSERT statement using the sequence value(s) manually.

Comment: thanks Gokhan Atil,the last method was useful!

Answer (score 1):

No, not any downside or side-effects on using the result scan approach to retrieve the required information.

Comment: can resultscan of last query id returns the correct value if  stored procedure is called by multiple processes