# How to use time travel in snowflake python with a query id?

Tags: python, string, data-binding, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53903693/4193058), I am trying to use the same pattern with the snowflake python connector. This has no issues:

```
snowflake_cursor.execute("""
set q_id = last_query_id();""")
snowflake_cursor.execute(""" 
select max(scenario_id) from scenarios at(statement=>$q_id);""")
```

However, I see relying on snowflake variables as ephemeral and would rather put this into a python variable; at the very least, if I wanted to time travel a day after the query is executed and the snowflake connection has been closed, I'll need some way to pass the query_id back in to execute:

```
snowflake_cursor.execute("""
select last_query_id();
""")
q_id = snowflake_cursor.fetchone()[0]
snowflake_cursor.execute("""
select max(scenario_id) from scenarios at(statement=>$%s);
""", q_id)
```

This gives the error, `unexpected '$'`, and everything I have tried to pass in the query id string has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding with `?` or `:1`. This works for me:

```sql
session.sql("select * from a_table at(statement=>:1);", (['01b2829a-0504-4f02-001e-2483024e7cda'])).collect()
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-example#qmark-or-numeric-binding